# Help with customising love it plugin (use within foreach)

Tags: plugins, jquery, ajax, php

I'm trying to tweak a love it plugin (by Daniel Pataki) which basically uses Ajax to update post meta when viewing single.php - all works fine when applying the funtionality on a single post view but I am looking to achieve this same functionality when viewing a custom page template that lists multiple posts in a foreach query.

So 5 posts listed with title, love count and increase love count button within a foreach, and I want to target just the selected post and update that individual posts meta on click

However, when updating the meta on any of my posts listed it's only applying it to the first post in the the query

The main plugin file Ajax-test.php

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ajax_test_enqueue_scripts' );
function ajax_test_enqueue_scripts() {
if( is_single() ) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'love', plugins_url( '/love.css', __FILE__ ) );
}

wp_enqueue_script( 'love', plugins_url( '/love.js', __FILE__ ),    array('jquery'), '1.0', true );

wp_localize_script( 'love', 'postlove', array(
    'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
));

}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_post_love_add_love', 'post_love_add_love' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_post_love_add_love', 'post_love_add_love' );

function post_love_add_love() {
$love = get_post_meta( $_REQUEST['post_id'], 'post_love', true );
$love++;
update_post_meta( $_REQUEST['post_id'], 'post_love', $love );
if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) { 
    echo $love;
    die();
}
else {
    wp_redirect( get_permalink( $_REQUEST['post_id'] ) );
    exit();
}
}
```

The Jquery plugin file - love.js

```
jQuery( document ).on( 'click', '.love-button', function() {
var post_id = jQuery(this).data('id');
jQuery.ajax({
    url : postlove.ajax_url,
    type : 'post',
    data : {
        action : 'post_love_add_love',
        post_id : post_id
    },
    success : function( response ) {
        jQuery('#love-count').html( response );
    }
});

return false;
})
```

And here is my page template which lists 5 posts within a while have.

```
 <?php get_header(); ?> 
 <div id="blog">
 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
  <div class="post"> 
       <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ? >   </a></h1>
       <div class="entry">  
            <?php the_content(); ?>


<ul>

<?php
global $post;
$events = get_posts('numberposts=5');
foreach($events as $event) :
setup_postdata($post);
?>
<li><?php echo get_the_title($event->ID); ?></li>

<?php $love = get_post_meta( $event->ID, 'post_love', true );
  $love = ( empty( $love ) ) ? 0 : $love;

  $love_text = '<p class="love-received"><a class="love-button"   href="' . admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php?action=post_love_add_love&post_id=' . $event->ID ) . '" data-id="' . $event->ID . '">give   love</a><span id="love-count">' . $love . '</span></p>'; ?>

       <?php echo $content . $love_text; ?> 


<?php endforeach; ?>

</ul> 


      </div>
  </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of problems-

`setup_postdata` doesn't work with any variable other than `$post`, so that line is doing nothing. This is explained on [the Codex page for `setup_postdata`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata).

`get_the_ID` doesn't accept any arguments, but it doesn't matter, you've already got the ID in `$event->ID`, just change all instances of `get_the_ID($event->ID)` to `$event->ID`.

Comment: Hi Milo, just tried that and it broke the page - giving me a blank white

Comment: You should [enable debugging](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and look at the error messages, you've made a syntax error.

Comment: Do I need to amend the main ajax-test.php file and love.js file as well? I made the edits you suggested to the post list template only.

Comment: Okay thanks, so close! I'll carry on trying to work this one out.

Comment: I cant figure this one out. I've tried enabling debugging too but cant see results, I know there must be a syntax error but strange how displayed fine before i made your edits

Comment: edit your question to show what your code currently looks like.

Comment: edited, I updated the main page template to change all instances of get_the_ID($event->ID) to $event->ID